# Advance search to find duplicate records in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I want to find similar data in Excel cell based on characters for example in one column I have `ABCDEF` and another column I have `DEAFBC`, so in this case both cell contains characters `abcdef`, any solution to match?

I tried like, similar, partial match options in Excel which didn't meet my results.

Comment: Show us an example of the source data and the results ie is it just text or alphanummeric, also show what you have tried so far...

Answer (score 0):

1. Separate each letter into it's own cell (text to columns, fixed width). Copy to a new column first if you want to keep the original data.
2. Sort each row (this is a little tricky, but it is possible - see my example.)
   [image: Example Image]
3. Combine the cells again by just stitching them together using `&`.
4. You can now sort to easily see duplicates or remove them etc.

The formula to paste into cell I2 in my example is:

```
=INDEX($B2:$G2, MIN(IF(SMALL(COUNTIF($B2:$G2, "<"&$B2:$G2), COLUMNS($H2:H2))=COUNTIF($B2:$G2, "<"&$B2:$G2), ROW($B2:$G2)-MIN(ROW($B2:$G2))+1)), MATCH(SMALL(COUNTIF($B2:$G2, "<"&$B2:$G2), COLUMNS($H2:H2)), COUNTIF($B2:$G2, "<"&INDEX($B2:$G2, MIN(IF(SMALL(COUNTIF($B2:$G2,"<"&$B2:$G2),COLUMNS($H2:H2))=COUNTIF($B2:$G2,"<"&$B2:$G2), ROW($B2:$G2)-MIN(ROW($B2:$G2))+1)), , 1)), 0), 1)
```

Make sure you hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> when exiting the cell, since this is an array formula.

Comment: Thanks for the response, i agree for your above response, but how to re sort that data to original format, for ex if its abdcfe ?

Comment: To Sort the Rows easily, e.g. if you have a *lot* of letters in each cell, select the data 1 row at a time, then in the Ribbon go "Data" then "Sort".  In the "Options", just set it to "Sort left to right".  @shivkumaratnure You'll notice that Step 1 says "Copy to a new column first if you want to keep the original data", so there is no need to re-sort to the original format, as wouldn't have been modified.

Comment: @Chronocidal - Select the data AFTER you've converted it to text to columns... also, I don't see how that makes it easier. You can just drag my formula as far as you need. Though, you would have to adjust it to reference a larger array if you have more letters... and importantly, it fails if there are blank spaces. There's a formula somewhere that will ignore blank spaces.

Comment: @shivkumaratnure - as pointed out above, why do you need to re-sort it? As I said in the instructions, copy the original data before you break it out using text to columns. That way, you still have the original data column untouched? Perhaps a better way then text to columns is just to use a formula (e.g. =LEFT(...,1).

Comment: If your text is of different lengths, you're going to have some blank cells that will break the formula unless you account for them. Here is a good example of how you'd have to adjust your formula to fix that: https://www.get-digital-help.com/2009/09/16/extract-a-unique-distinct-list-sorted-alphabetically-removing-blanks-from-a-range-in-excel/